# Get the value of ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angularjs project, I have problem while using `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat`. When i select the value in select box, the selectbox automatically gets selected with previous selected value. I think this is due to the same `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat`. How can we fix this issue?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <select class="selectbox_menulist"  ng-change="endpoint.showEndPointStatsData()" ng-model="graphSelect.value">
        <option ng-repeat="opt in mapOptions" value="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.type}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.mapOptions = [
    { value: "bytes",type:"Bytes/sec" },
    { value: "packets",type:"Packets/sec"},
    { value: "megabytes",type:"Megabytes/sec"}
];

 showEndPointStatsData: function() {
        console.log('Function called ====');
        console.log($scope.graphSelect.value);
```

}

Comment: there is no same ng-model inside the ng-repeat. could you provide the code of showEndPointStatsData to track about 'selecting previous value'

Comment: `ng-repeat` with `<option>` is not the best solution use `ng-options="opt.type as opt.value for opt in mapOptions"` into the `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Use `array` to store value of mutli `ng-model` in `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
<select class="selectbox_menulist"  ng-change="endpoint.showEndPointStatsData($index)" ng-model="graphSelect[$index]">
    <option ng-repeat="opt in mapOptions" value="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.type}}</option>
</select>
</div>
  $scope.mapOptions = [{ value: "bytes",type:"Bytes/sec" }, { value: "packets",type:"Packets/sec"},{ value: "megabytes",type:"Megabytes/sec"}];
$scope.graphSelect = new Array($scope.data.length);

showEndPointStatsData: function(index) {
    console.log('Function called ====');
    console.log($scope.graphSelect[index]);
```

Comment: $scope.data is undefined @Yin Gang

Comment: it should be $scope.graphSelect = new Array($scope.mapOptions .length);

Comment: As your html, `ng-repeat="x in data"`, how possible `$scope.data` is `undefined`?

Comment: that was my mistake.by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome, just be care, `length` of `graphSelect` equals number of `<select>`, rather than number of `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-model inside ng-repeat
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sirhc/z9cGm/)

The above link has good description on how to use it with examples